# Powershell Custom Sorting

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have below content in a txt file which will be read by powershell and should be rearranged based on a custom condition

**File: abc.txt**

```
General
User1/Alert
User1/LogicApp
General/Abc
User2/Alert
User2/LogicApp
```

Above should be sorted with custom condition where if **"General"** exists, it should be on top of the list and if string **"LogicApp"** exists, it should be next to General. Hence, output should be something like below

```
General
General/abc
User1/LogicApp
User2/LogicApp
User1/Alert
User2/Alert
```

If string **"General"** doesn't exist, then string **"LogicApp"** should be taking priority. Can we do this custom sorting in Powershell ?

Answer (score 5):

You can perform custom sorting using `-Property` parameter of [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object), which accepts multiple expressions.

```
'General','User1/Alert','User1/LogicApp','General/Abc','User2/Alert','User2/LogicApp' | 
  Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={$_ -like '*General*'}; Descending=$true}, {if($_ -like '*LogicApp*') {0} else {1}}, {$_}
```

General and LogicApp are sorted using different methods just to illustrate. Last element `{$_}` assures alphabetical sort.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [AdamL's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78066550/45375) with a two-criterion solution using a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement to initially categorize the input strings, which is perhaps easier to conceptualize:

```bash
# Sample input lines.
$lines = @'
General
User1/Alert
User1/LogicApp
General/Abc
User2/Alert
User2/LogicApp
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$lines |
  Sort-Object -Property { 
      # 1st criterion: sort by presence of 'General', 'LogicApp', anything else, in order.
      switch -Regex ($_) { 'General' { 0 } 'LogicApp' { 1 } default { 2 } } 
    }, 
    { 
      # 2nd criterion: sort by the strings as a whole.
      $_ 
    }
```